# Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?) on VMware Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, apt, updates, vmware

I am working on my home wifi network. I able access internet (through browser) from both guest as well as host OS. But I am unable to `sudo apt-get update`

Please visit [this link](https://pastebin.com/QUaaWTKM) to see the output of the update command.

I have tried changing the interface type of the VM from bridge to NAT. But the error persists.

I have read the other questions on the topic. But none of the answers tell why the browser is able access the internet while apt-get is not?

I have complete access to my home router how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error is about a third-party repository that you added (GetDeb).
APT is working fine and the error prevents installing/updating from that repo only.

Any other installations/updates should work and no, it has nothing to do with (your) internet access. It's just the way those type of error messages were designed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I commented out the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list` and now it works fine. Does the above file exist in ubuntu by default?

Comment: You're welcome. Alternatively you could have removed it using Software & Updates (GUI). No, it doesn't exist in Ubuntu by default. It's a third-party repository not managed by Ubuntu, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Do you recommend removing the file altogether?

Comment: Not a file, a repository and... It depends. If you need software only available at that repo I suggest trying again in a few days. Sometimes this are just temporary problems in the server. But if you never installed software exclusively available trough that repo then, of course, remove it, it has no purpose.